# how to display records from table based on single word from multiple words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

Row 1:

```
did: 1
brand_name: Aarther P (100+500)
generic: Paracetamol, Aceclofenac
tradename: Aarther P (100+500)
manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals
unit: 500mg/100mg
type: Tablet
quantity: 10Tablet
price: 27.9
```

Row 2:

```
did: 2
brand_name: Aarther-P
generic: Aceclofenac, Paracetamol
tradename: Aarther-P
manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals
unit: 100mg/500mg
type: Tablet
quantity: 10Tablet
price: 27.9
```

If i search records based on generic like 'paracetamol' I want to display the results as follows:

Row 1:

```
did: 1
brand_name: Aarther P (100+500)
generic: Paracetamol
tradename: Aarther P (100+500)
manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals
unit: 500mg/100mg
type: Tablet
quantity: 10Tablet
price: 27.9
```

Row 2:

```
did: 2
brand_name: Aarther-P
generic:  Paracetamol
tradename: Aarther-P
manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals
unit: 100mg/500mg
type: Tablet
quantity: 10Tablet
price: 27.9
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you tried? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To display results like the above in row wise manner, better to do in your front end application program which is using MySQL as backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select `did`, `brand_name`, 'Paracetamol' as `generic`, `tradename`, 
`manfactured`, `unit`, `type`, 
`quantity`, `price` from table1 where 
find_in_set ('Paracetamol',generic) 
or find_in_set (' Paracetamol',generic)
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d556/7)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get first two records of your table then

```
select * from table limit 2;
```

If intention is to get all records whose generic column value is Paracetmol then

```
select * from table where generic='Paracetmol';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE generic LIKE '%paracetamol%'
```

This will select any record that has 'parcetamol' in the generic row. It will also select records that have 'paracetamol' and any other data in any combination for example:

'paracetamol, asprin'
'codine, parcetamol'
'asprin, paracetamol, asprin'

Comment: The '%' symbol acts as a wildcard so, '%para' will select records where the 'para' is the last word and, 'para%' will select records where 'para' is the first word.